# Is there a way to save the "Export As" Scale All Sizes in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export

Photoshop now has a nice feature you can right-click on an Artboard and choose "Export As.."

Once you do this on the left side of the screen you have the ability to add multiple sizes for scaling with the appropriate ratios and suffixes.

This is a game changer (and something that Sketch does really well). However, it is very annoying these export sizes cannot be saved and reused over again. They persist for the duration that the document is opened but if you close and reopen your PSD they are not saved.

Any ideas on how to make these export preferences persist? We are constantly creating copies of Artboards, changing a few things and re-exporting so this would save us a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Generate Image Assets.

You can use [Image Asset](https://helpx.adobe.com/au/photoshop/using/generate-assets-layers.html) markup on any layer, group or Artboard and do just about any export option with it.

Because these are hard-coded into your document, they are always there.

### Make an Image Asset Template - [PSDT](https://youtu.be/vsOmsz6cGtI)

If you want to have the same options on multiple PSD's, you could set up a template with the Image Asset syntax using blank Layers, Groups and Artboards, then populate them as required.

To save as a PSDT - Photoshop Template, select **PSD** and add a **T** to the end to get PSDT.

Photoshop Templates always save new documents separate to the template, making sure the Template always stays in its original state.

---

[image]

### This is how it would look if using it on Artboards - Windows:

*My example with outputted files in a folder at different sizes:

[image]

[image]

---

### Changing Your Image Assets File Types With Export As

With Image Assets set up, you can still use Export as if you want to change any of them without changing your syntax.

Just select the file you want to change, set your preference and export as normal.

[image]

[image]

---

### [Using Image Assets on Layers:](https://cantina.co/workflow-creating-assets-photoshop-generator/)

Here is how Image Assets syntax looks on layers:

[image]